# ui-router root call not possible?

Tags: angularjs, azure, url-rewriting, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I've applied ui-router routing and it works just fine.

However when I publish the website to azure I'm getting this on the root page

[image]

Navigating to the /home url works fine and also all the other urls are working fine but I want the main root view to be the same as /home.

How can I achieve that?

I'm using Visual Studio blank project in which I have all the Angular functionality.

ui-router logic:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
          .state('root', {
              url: '',
              data: {
                  css: [
                      '/assets/css/homepage.css',
                      {
                          name: 'layout1',
                          href: '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'
                      },
                      {
                          name: 'layout2',
                          href: '/assets/css/style.css'
                      },
                      {
                          name: 'layout3',
                          href: '/assets/css/responsive.css'
                      },
                      {
                          name: 'layout4',
                          href: '/assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
                      }
                  ]
              },
              views: {
                  'header': {
                      templateUrl: '/views/partials/header.html'
                  },
                  'content': {
                      templateUrl: '/views/home/index.html',
                      controller: 'homeController'
                  },
                  'footer': {
                      templateUrl: '/views/partials/footer.html'
                  }
              }
          })
        .state("home", {
            url: "/",
            data: {
                css: [
                    '/assets/css/homepage.css',
                    {
                        name: 'layout1',
                        href: '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'layout2',
                        href: '/assets/css/style.css'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'layout3',
                        href: '/assets/css/responsive.css'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'layout4',
                        href: '/assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'
                    }
                ]
            },
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl: '/views/partials/header.html'
                },
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: '/views/home/index.html',
                    controller: 'homeController'
                },
                'footer': {
                    templateUrl: '/views/partials/footer.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state("ourteam", {
            url: "/ourteam",
            data: {
                css: [
                    '/assets/css/responsive.css',
                    '/assets/css/style.css'
                ]
            },
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl: '/views/partials/header.html'
                },
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: '/views/home/our-team.html'
                },
                'footer': {
                    templateUrl: '/views/partials/footer.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state("contact", {
            url: "/contact",
            data: {
                css: [
                    '/assets/css/responsive.css',
                    '/assets/css/style.css'
                ]
            },
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl: '/views/partials/header.html'
                },
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: '/views/home/contact.html'
                },
                'footer': {
                    templateUrl: '/views/partials/footer.html'
                }
            }
        })
});
```

Comment: hi, any update?

Answer (score 0):

Can you publish a code snippet or at least the ui-router configuration?

PS: I think it's not the best idea to create a google framework boilerplate with a microsoft IDE. If you review your own code and build it in parts self, you will better unterstand what happens.

Comment: Hi Marcel I just added the code for the ui-router configuration. I'm just trying to load the main state from the root url.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `""` is the alias of `"/"`, according the comments among https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/185#issuecomment-19661148.

Please try the following configuration:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
          url: '/',
          ...
          })
    .state('home',{
          url:'/home',
          ...
          })
```